# Duplicate and Out of Sequence Numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Each patient should have unique randomID and these randomID's should be in sequence order, So I should
bring back (Duplicate RandomID) and (Out of Sequence RandomID)

here is my query

```
declare @valueCheck table
(RowNumber Int Identity
,PatientID varchar(25)
,RandomID varchar(25))

insert into @ValueCheck
(PatientID, RandomID)

select
PatientID
, RandomID

From   dbo.CurrentData

where QuestionID= 200
order by patientid, RandomID
```

if I apply this condition, I'll get (out of sequence RandomID)

```
Select s1.PatientID, s1. RandomID as OutOFSequence
From @ValueCheck s1
Left Join @ValueCheck s2
On s1.RandomID = s2.RandomID – 1
Where s2.RandomID is Null
```

and if I apply this , I'll get (Duplicate RandomID)

```
select * from @ValueCheck
where RandomID in 
(Select RandomID
From @ValueCheck
Group by RandomID
Having Count(RandomID) > 1)
```

what I want is, I want a table that brings both condition together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do a union query.

```
Select s1.PatientID, s1. RandomID, 'OutOFSequence'
From @ValueCheck s1
Left Join @ValueCheck s2
On s1.RandomID = s2.RandomID – 1
Where s2.RandomID is Null
union all
select PatientID, RandomID, 'Duplicate' from @ValueCheck
where RandomID in 
(Select RandomID
From @ValueCheck
Group by RandomID
Having Count(RandomID) > 1)
```

Comment: I couldn't use union all, The error message says: All queries combined using a UNION, must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Comment: Your field counts and types should match in both the union queries. I have updated the query to reflect this change.